# Chart two columns of data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10

I have two columns of data: RPM and MPH. I want an Excek line chart of RPM versus MPH. Then I would like to create a formula for the best fit.

Comment: Thanks for telling us. Do you have a question?

Comment: How do you define best fit?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're using a more recent version of Excel. To make a line graph of your data in the way you described, copy the data columns for MPH and RPM side-by-side in that order. Then select both columns. Click 'Insert' > 'line graph'. To add a trend line and formula for your data, right click on the newly made graph and click 'add trendline' in the dropdown menu. A panel should pop up on the right hand side of your screen with options for the different types of fittings (linear, exponential, logarithmic, etc.).

Hope that helps!